# Using same key for encryption and ECBC-MAC k2

Tags: mac, cbc-mac

ECBC-MAC: $E_{k_2}(CBC-MAC_{k_1}(m))$

If we use same key for encryption (CTR or CFB) and k2 (end tag encryption) in ECBC-MAC in encrypt-than-MAC sheme, is it secure?